# How do I remove the last instance of a character combination using formulas?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, formula-field, screen-flow

I am currently creating a flow where a text collection is combined into a single text variable using a loop. After each item of the collection is added to the text variable I add a divider such as `,`  to differentiate between the different items in the collection. The problem is that whenever the loop finishes the variable ends with my divider and I want to avoid that.

An example of what my current formula does:

```
Input - name_collection = "Dean, Thomas, James, "

SUBSTITUTE(name_collection, ", ", "")

Output - name_collection = "DeanThomasJames"
```

The output I was hoping for:

```
name_collection = "Dean, Thomas, James"
```

Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are always anticipating that the last two characters are going to be ", " (because that's how you're constructing the list), you could use [LEFT()](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5#LEFT).

Something like, `LEFT(name_collection, LEN(name_collection) - 2)` should return the string minus the two end characters.

Comment: SUBSTR() is available in Flow? - `MID` is what I would have used

Comment: @cropredy You are right, `SUBSTR` is not recognized inside of a flow. How would I use `MID` to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Very good point - you'd think I would have caught that! I updated my answer -- though I prefer LEFT over MID ;-)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much!